# Textarea draggable+resizable both

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Teatarea/Textbox/any Element excluding DIV draggable and resizable both at time is not working.
I am doing something wrong?

Here is My simple Code:

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="test"/>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$("#test").resizable();
$("#test").draggable({
            cancel: '',
            containment: "parent"
        });
```

Above statements looks OK for me.
Can anybody gives me some pointers about this.

**EDIT:**

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/570kjym3/)

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you could provide the jsfiddle
Also did you add the above code insode document ready

```
$(function(){
  $("#test").resizable();
  $("#test").draggable({
            cancel: '',
            containment: "parent"
        });


});
```

Comment: Obviously Both are under ready function. If i use both at a time gives problem. Only draggable working fine and i add resizable its not working. Please see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6SF2v/58/)

I think here is what something you need. Hope it helps. Check out the fiddle. Thanx.

HTML:

```
  <section id="container" class="ui-widget-content">
     <h3 class="ui-widget-header">Containment</h3>
       <span id="draggable">*  
         <input type="text "id="resizable" class="ui-state-active" value="This is input box">
      </span>
  </section>
```

Javascript:

```
     $(function() {
        $( "#resizable" ).resizable({
           containment: "#container"
        });
        $( "#draggable" ).draggable({containment: "#container"});
    });
```